# Migrating spring controllers to restful web service controller

Tags: json, spring

I am using spring 3 MVC currently in my web application and I am intereseted in migrating all my controllers to restful web services using spring 3 restful (@ResponseBody) feature. I am using JSON request and response. but I am not sure how to do session management when using JSON response so that i can have the same data available across multiple web request.
Please suggest all possilbe scenerios with pros and cons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the session inside your controller, simply add the Request as a parameter of your method, and Spring will do the job for you.
Then you can call `getSession()` on the request and here you go.

```
public void myMethodInController(HttpServletRequest request) {
      HttpSession session = request.getSession();
}
```

This has nothing to do with the responsebody, it is pure Spring MVC.

Edit: If you want to share the form data between the controller throug the session, you can for example do :

```
public ResourceOne myMethodInControllerOne(HttpServletRequest request, DataOne data) {

      // call some injected service to create a ResourceOne
      ResourceOne response = service.doSomething(data);

      if ( null != response) {
          HttpSession session = request.getSession();
          session.setAttribute("dataOne", data);
      }
      return response;
}


public ResourceTwo myMethodInControllerTwo(HttpServletRequest request, DataTwo data) {

      HttpSession session = request.getSession();
      DataOne priorData = (DataOne) session.getAttribute("dataOne");

      // call some injected service to create a ResourceTwo
      ResourceTwo response = service.doSomething(data, priorData);
      return response;
}
```

But this is not really RestFul. Rest imply a stateless API. Wouldn't it be better to change your API and send DataOne and DataTwo in the second method ?

Comment: It's like , there are multiple controllers for doing various operations and i have to convert all controllers to restful web service. previously we were storing all the data in session but now since each controller will act like web service and we will send the response as JSON. I think, httpsession will not be useful. Please note that in front end we are using node.js

Comment: If there are multiple controller and each acting like web service which send JSON response. when i call my first web service controller for the first time with some data. how can i make available the same data when i invoke other controller.

Comment: Use the `HttpSession` as described in the answer above. REST/JSON web services are not special cases.

Comment: I think , i am not clear here. My request and response both are in JSON format. Also if i give you a example , suppose there are two restful web service controller. First one gets called with some JSON input and if input is ok then in JSON response sucsess message would be written. if response is success then second restful web service controller will be called. but while calling  second time web service controller and i also want data which i had sent to the first controller. In short , i want to share data between two rest web services call

Comment: edited my answer to show you how to use the session to share object, but this is not very restfull